# Auto Save form fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Please I want to achieve this: Submitting students scores onblur the form input field And these are my codes

Form.php

```
    <span id="ref_report"></span><br>
Student One:<input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' id='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin'id="admin" value='st1'><br>
Students Two  <input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' id='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin[]'id="admin" value='st2'><br>
Student  three  <input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' id='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin[]'id="admin" value='st3'><br>
```

//jquery

```
 $('#ref_no').blur(function(){
            var query_string = $(this).val();
            if(query_string.length>0)
            {
            //var filter = /^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{4,}$/;
            //if ( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()@#!?]+$/', $string) )
            var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9/#-]{1,}$/;// this allows special characters "/" and "-"
                if (!(filter.test(query_string))) {
                    $('#ref_report').html('<font color=red>This #Ref No. is not accepted</font>');
                    $('.login-apt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    return false;
                }
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "validate.php",
                    //data: query_string,
                    data: {ref_no:query_string},//ref_no

                    success: function(data)
                        {
                        if(data=='exist')
                        {
                            $('#ref_report').html('<font color=red><b>This #Ref. Number does not exist here</b></font>');
                            $('.login-apt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#ref_report').html('<img src=yes.png><font color="Green">Accepted</font>');
                            $('.login-apt').removeAttr('disabled',false);

                        }               
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

bellow are the php codes i used on the validat.php to do the trick:

```
if(isset($_POST['ref_no']))
{
    $ref_no = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['ref_no']));
    $admin = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['admin']));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_cms` WHERE `admin`= '$ref_no'";
    $myquery = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($myquery) !=0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery);

  for($i=0;$i< count($_POST['ref_no']); $i++){
     $data = $_POST['ref_no'][$i];
     $admin = $_POST['admin'][$i];

   $sql="INSERT INTO `tbl_cms` (`admin`, `content`) values('$admin', '" . $data . "')";
           mysql_query($sql);

           }

                echo 'not exist';

    }
    else
    {
            echo 'exist';

    }
}
```

I have a very simple MySQL table where I want the Scores for each students with their admin to automatically stored as key-in the score.It looks like that:

```
admin   Content
std1     3      
std2     5 
std3     6 
  .......................................................
```

My problem is that the code work but save only the content of the first form field i.e std1 score only. Instead of saving the scores of the three students
Please guide me on how to perfect this. Thanks

Comment: You are using same id="ref_no" for several inputs. Try using `.$(".ref_no").blur(function() ... ` and add class attribute on each input `class="ref_no" ` . Remember, The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: #sayonara Thank you so much, it worked but I think my validate.php too is having some issues,kindly help to check too

Answer (score 1):

You can not have multiple `id` attributes with the same value. Use class instead:

```
Student One:<input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' class='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin' id="admin-1" value='st1'><br>
Students Two  <input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' class='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin[]' id="admin-2" value='st2'><br>
Student  three  <input  type="text" name='ref_no[]' class='ref_no'><input  type="text" name='admin[]' id="admin-3" value='st3'><br>

$('.ref_no').blur(...);
```

Note I also changed `id="admin"` to `id="admin-1"` etc.

Comment: thank you @Martin Adámek ,please also check the validate.php code too

Comment: What is the problem there? You did not noted other problem than this one if I see correctly.

Comment: its no storing student admin number [ admin ] and i dont know why and also only one digit of inserted scores is storing as scores [ content ]

Comment: its no storing student admin number [ admin ] and i dont know why and also only one digit of inserted scores is storing as scores [ content ]

Comment: Well you are trying to work with `$_POST['admin']` in you PHP script, but you are not passing that when making the request in JS.

Comment: There are more problems tho, in HTML on first input row, you have just `name='admin'` instead of `name='admin[]'`. Then you need to pass that value together with `ref_no` value in your JS .